# Method Added in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

In Ruby, one can create callbacks for when methods are defined on an object:

```
module Chatty
  def self.method_added(method_name)
    puts "Adding #{method_name.inspect}"
  end
  def self.some_class_method() end
  def some_instance_method() end
end
# => Adding :some_instance_method
```

Does Python have any similar callback?

Comment: Not for methods added during class creation. Afterwards it's just `__setattr__` like any other attribute.

Comment: You can do this with a metaclass.

Comment: What is a good use case for this functionality? I think it would be cool if you provided some motivation too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, methods are just *attributes* that happen to be callable<sup>*</sup>. You'd have to hook in to attributes being set to see new methods being added to a class.

You'd have to use a [*metaclass*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) to intercept new attributes being added to a class:

```
import types

class NewMethodAlerter(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
            print(f'New method {name} added!')
        super().__setattr__(name, obj)


class Demo(metaclass=NewMethodAlerter):
    def existing_method(self):
        pass

def new_method(self): pass
Demo.new_method = new_method
```

which then looks like this:

```
>>> class Demo(metaclass=NewMethodAlerter):
...     def existing_method(self):
...         pass
...
>>> def new_method(self): pass
>>> Demo.new_method = new_method
New method new_method added!
```

If you wanted to know about the *initial* set of attributes, the result of executing the `class` body, then you have two options: use a metaclass, or in Python 3.6 and up, the [`__init_subclass__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). Either one is called to create new classes, and can be used to inspect the attributes:

```
class InitialMethodAlerter(type):
    def __new__(typ, name, bases, attrs):
        for name, obj in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
                print(f'Method {name} defined!')
        return super().__new__(typ, name, bases, attrs)

class Demo(metaclass=InitialMethodAlerter):
    def existing_method(self):
        pass
```

or the `__init_subclass__` method:

```
class InitialMethodAlerter:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
            if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
                print(f'Method {name} defined!')

class Demo(InitialMethodAlerter):
    def existing_method(self):
        pass
```

You may want to read up on metaclasses at [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

---

<sup>*</sup>Well, the attributes are *functions* actually. Functions are [descriptor objects](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which causes them to be bound when accessed via an instance. That binding process produces a method object, that when called takes the original function and passes in the instance to which it was bound.

Comment: So there's no way to intercept methods defined in the class definition?

Comment: @faraz: what are you trying to achieve here? I may have misunderstood. The metaclass is *also* told about all the initial attributes for the class, as the class is created.

Comment: I'd expect `New method existing_method added!` to appear after the class is defined.

Comment: @faraz: your question was confusing me there, because of the terminology 'added'. I've updated the question, but it's more and more a duplicate of [What is a metaclass in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/100003) now.

Comment: @faraz One small clarification to help you understand why you are not seeing the message about the existing method: the `__setattr__` method isn't called when the class body is executed and all of the initial class members are created. There is a separate set of machinery invoked for class *creation*.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've just started diving into metaprogramming in Python, and this was immensely helpful.